# Item description table to create a corresponding entry into the notes table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am still fairly new to rails & just getting the hang of it.  So my scenario is that when an item description table is being filled out by an employee, I would require automatically a corresponding entry into the Notes Table, with the items that have been selected from the Item Description table to also show up in the Notes view.

What is the best way to go about this? Can anybody suggest a course of action?
For example : first you must etc... then you must etc....

My model for my item_description.rb is:

```
class ItemDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
end
```

my model for my note.rb is :

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
end
```

In my item_description controller my create block of code looks like this:

```
def create
@job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
if @job.item_descriptions.create(item_description_param)
  redirect_to job_item_description_path(@job), :notice => 'Equipment was successfully created.'
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @item_description.save
    format.html { redirect_to @item_description, notice: 'Item description was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @item_description }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @item_description.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: We need some more information to help you out. What is the relationship between `item_descriptions` and `notes`? Which notes view are you talking about? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jken13579 Sorry about that so when I scaffolded my item_descriptions table it is referenced to my Jobs table, not my notes table. I would need a corresponding entry to appear on the notes once the Item_descriptions has been filled out.

Comment: Can you post your model code for each with one, with the relationships?

Comment: @Jken13579 I have posted both models. Thank you for looking into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that when you submit a form for a new `item_description`, you'd like a new `note` object to be created based on the value(s) that are chosen in this new `item_description` form?

If so, can you please post the form for the new `item_description` as well as schema for the `item_description` model and the `note` model (what attributes do they have)?

It seems to me that this would be a simple job from your `item_description` create action.  Inside create, just create a new note and pass it the value(s) you gathered from the params of your `item_description` form

Hopefully I'm understanding the situation correctly?

EDIT:

Whatever the attributes are that your collecting in the form (whether they be strings, or whatever), everything is available in your params hash.  Below is code for your controller (assuming the values you're collecting for the new `note` are represented in the code below by `job_attribute_1` and `job_attribute_2` - or however many attributes you need to create a new `note`).

```
def create
@job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
if @job.item_descriptions.create(item_description_param)
  @job.notes.create!(job_attribute_1: params[:job_attribute_1], job_attribute_2: params[:job_attribute_2]
  redirect_to job_item_description_path(@job), :notice => 'Equipment was successfully created.'
end
```

Comment: the form for the item_description is very long

Comment: do you mean that I would have to include this in the create section of my controller for my item_description? I have already included both models for my note.rb and item_description.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
job = Job.create!
job.item_description.create! field1: "information1", field2: "information2"
job.note.create! field3: "information3", field4: "information4"
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I need a corresponding entry in the notes table not the job table

Comment: if you don't need job then your relationship should be a one to one relationship between item_description and note

Comment: you should include this code in your model that deals with processing the employees input

Comment: for the field1: what am I supposed to include there?